# SHA-1 in haskell producing wrong hashes

Tags: haskell, hash, sha1

I wrote a program to perform SHA-1 in haskell, and while it does produce hashes, they do not match with the ones produced by other SHA-1 programs

Example: `cat`
hashes to: `b5be86bc8bccfc24b01b093228ebb96fc92fa804` but is supposed to hash to `9d989e8d27dc9e0ec3389fc855f142c3d40f0c50`

My code is:

```
(old code omitted)
```

I have no idea what is wrong. Can someone tell me where I made a mistake?

**Edit:**
I fixed the stuff that was pointed out, however it is still not working. It works correctly up until the inner loop. 
I cleaned up the code so the functions for the inner loop are available as `f1`, `f2` and `f3`
`cat` now interestingly hashes to `ebe6c9fa1afa0ef5a0ca80bab251fd41cc29127e`.

Code:

```
import Data.Word
import Data.Bits
import Data.Char (ord, intToDigit)
import Data.Binary (encode, decode)
import Numeric (showHex, showIntAtBase)
import System.IO (stdin)
import Data.Sequence ((<|), (|>))
import qualified Data.Sequence as S
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
type Quintuple32 = (Word32, Word32, Word32, Word32, Word32)

addQuintuple (a, b, c, d, e) (f, g, h, i, j) =
    (a + f, b + g, c + h, d + i, e + j)

shower :: Quintuple32 -> String
shower (a, b, c, d, e) = concatMap (`showHex` "") [a, b, c, d, e]

hash :: Int -> S.Seq Word32 -> Quintuple32 -> Quintuple32
hash i w h@(a, b, c, d, e)
    | i < 20 = hash (i + 1) w (newhash (f1 h + k1))
    | i < 40 = hash (i + 1) w (newhash (f2 h + k2))
    | i < 60 = hash (i + 1) w (newhash (f3 h + k3))
    | i < 80 = hash (i + 1) w (newhash (f2 h + k4))
    | otherwise = h
  where (k1, k2, k3, k4) = (0x5A827999, 0x6ED9EBA1, 0x8F1BBCDC, 0xCA62C1D6)
        newhash a' = (rotate a 5 + a' + e + (w `S.index` i), a, rotate b 30, c, d)

f1 :: Quintuple32 -> Word32
f1 (_, b, c, _, _) = (b .&. c) .|. (complement b .&. c)

f2 :: Quintuple32 -> Word32
f2 (_, b, c, d, _) = b `xor` c `xor` d

f3 :: Quintuple32 -> Word32
f3 (_, b, c, d, _) = (b .&. c) .|. (b .&. d) .|. (c .&. d)

starting :: Quintuple32
starting = (0x67452301
           , 0xEFCDAB89
           , 0x98BADCFE
           , 0x10325476
           , 0xC3D2E1F0)

hasher :: Quintuple32 -> S.Seq Word32 -> Quintuple32
hasher acc x = addQuintuple acc (hash 0 (extend x) acc)

process :: B.ByteString -> Quintuple32
process = foldl hasher starting . chunks . pad

extend :: S.Seq Word32 -> S.Seq Word32
extend = extend' 16

extend' :: Int -> S.Seq Word32 -> S.Seq Word32
extend' 80 a = a
extend' i a = extend' (i + 1) (a |> xored)
  where xored = rotate ((a `S.index` (i - 3)) `xor`
                        (a `S.index` (i - 8)) `xor`
                        (a `S.index` (i - 14)) `xor`
                        (a `S.index` (i - 16))) 1

toBytes :: String -> B.ByteString
toBytes = B.pack . map (fromIntegral . ord)

splitEvery n xs
    | B.null xs = S.empty
    | otherwise = B.take n xs <| splitEvery n (B.drop n xs)

chunks :: B.ByteString -> [S.Seq Word32]
chunks xs
    | B.null xs = []
    | otherwise = x : chunks (B.drop 64 xs)
  where x = fmap decode (splitEvery 4 (B.take 64 xs))

pad :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
pad xs = B.append (add0 $ add1 xs) length64
  where length64 = encode (fromIntegral (8 * B.length xs) :: Word64)

add1 :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
add1 = flip B.append (B.singleton 128)

add0 :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
add0 xs
    | modulo /= 448 = add0 $ B.append xs (B.singleton 0)
    | otherwise = xs
  where modulo = (B.length xs * 8) `rem` 512
```

Also, a small question: is something like `(a, b) = (8, 9)` an acceptable thing to do to set multiple variables?

Comment: To save us some time figuring out your code, what is the `main` function you used to test "cat"?

Comment: @Alec `shower $ process $ toBytes "cat"`

Comment: Writing tests for those functions which contain a lot of logic might help you figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, another one of these!

Two errors jump out at me immediately:

```
pad :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
pad xs = B.append (add0 $ add1 xs) length64
  where length64 = encode (fromIntegral (B.length xs) :: Word64)
```

Notice the length you append is supposed to be the bit length, not the byte length.

```
add1 :: B.ByteString -> B.ByteString
add1 = flip B.append (B.singleton 255)
```

Notice `255 /= 0b10000000` and the pad is supposed to be the later.

In general you debug these by 1) going over the spec again and again. 2) Comparing to another implementation, such as Adam Wick's SHA package, and comparing for equality at as fine grained level as possible.

EDIT: There are two more bugs, basically transcription errors.  Look around a bit and shout if you're still stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed the things you said and a few other things I noticed, and got it working correctly up until (including) the extend step, i.e. before the actual hash function happens but I really am still stuck. My code is here: http://lpaste.net/4913292567711318016

Comment: I don't have time right now to look at this new version, but the `hash` function is wrong (bad name seeing as that is the inner, compression, function of the SHA-1 hash).  Dropping in a version of `hash` from another SHA1 implementation results in proper functionality at least for the empty string.  You caught the 'c/d' naming and 'shift/rotate' issues I had seen earlier.

Comment: I thought that name was appropriate since it is the function that did the actual hashing. I edited the original post with code I updated even more, but I really am still stuck

Comment: `(b .&. c) .|. (complement b .&. c) != (b .&. c) .|. (complement b .&. d)`

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I didn't catch that.